# Hadoop - Problem with Text to float conversion

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a csv file containing key-value pairs; it can have multiple records for the same key. I am writing a mapreduce program to aggregate this data - for each key, it is supposed to give the frequency of key and sum of values for the key.

My mapper reads the csv file and emits both key and value as Text type eventhough they are numeric (doing this way because I am running into problems using FloatWritable for value).

In the reducer, when I try to convert the Text value to float, I am running into NumberFormatException and the value shown in the error is not even in my input.

Heres my code:

```
public static class AggReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
    private Text result = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<FloatWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int numTrips = 0;
      int totalFare = 0;

      for (Text val : values) {
        totalFare += Float.parseFloat(val.toString());
        numTrips++;
      }


      String resultStr = String.format("%1s,%2s", numTrips, totalFare);
      result.set(resultStr);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }
```

Note : I made the reducer produce mapper's output without any changes and that gave the expected output

Answer (score 0):

> running into NumberFormatException and the value shown in the error is not even in my input

Well, that's quite impossible. Somewhere the value needs to be in your input or generated mapper output. Try catch works just as well in a reducer as anywhere else, though

FWIW, use DoubleWritable